# How to have a web page load at the bottom of the site.

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, web

I am creating a reverse site, meaning the opening spot on the page is at the bottom and you scroll up to go through content. a simple command to explain what i mean is http://url.com/#bottom (or #footer). However i want to avoid having to create an "ENTER" site page that lines to #bottom and i cannot use a URL redirect to any #adress.

No im not trying to spoof some free server or something, you can checkout what im trying to do at Sean-holt.com. (note im still in the beginning of the work. but just go to the bottom and then scroll up, I want the site to open at the picture of the world).

I just want the first place the viewer to see is the bottom of the page and then have to scroll up.

How can i accomplish this?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!!! you guys rock!

(P.S. This is the first time i have used stack Overflow!)

Comment: did you try javascript onload?

Comment: Um no, this is looks like it would work pretty well if there is no other way, but it would be slightly slower, but definitely better than nothing! Iv never used this script before and the example is for text, how would you set it for a redirect? Thanks! Does anyone else know a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do it with Javascript/jQuery instead of redirecting again

Put this in the head tag of your file

```
<script>
// after dom is loaded
$(function() {
  // scroll all the way down
  $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height());
});
</script>
```

Comment: I like the look of this, but i dont know anything about javascript/jQuery, How do i impliment this, im finding nothing on the web really.

Comment: It's really powerful and widely used. You can easily achieve things, like moving stuff around or manipulating elements. -- You could either download it from [jquery.com](http://jquery.com) or you implement it from Googles online repository: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Which has the slight advantage that the user may already have it in the cache. (*1.7.1 is the latest version by the way*) For more information you can check the docs on jquery.com or for better overview you can use [jqapi](http://jqapi.com).

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="window.location.hash = 'footer'">
```

Where the footer has `id="footer"`.

Comment: This is defiantly better than having to refresh the page, and is currently implemented, but still slower than i would prefer. But it works great thanks very very much!

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful for you.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

I did not use this but may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Lee's idea is great.. Just add or subtract something to achieve your ideal position.

I've done it like this:

```
<script>
        // after dom is loaded
        $(function() {
          // scroll all the way down
          $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - ($(window).height() + 280));
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This seems like a comment on @DanLee's answer rather than its own answer.